# Arabic characters appear as boxes in Kobo

Tags: epub, kobo, fonts

I use Kobo Glo HD for ePub, it has problem displaying Arabic characters in library list and in the book's footer, they appear boxes, I tried many fonts; Dubai, Rashiq, publisher default fonts, etc. The problem still, I hope someone has a solution. [image]

Answer (score 1):

Two possible solutions:

- [Embed needed fonts](https://creativemarket.com/blog/how-to-create-an-ebook-embedded-fonts) in the epub document. That should allow proper display on most e-readers.
- If there are specific Kobo e-readers on which this document should display correctly, such as devices used by an organization, [install the needed fonts on the e-reader](https://goodereader.com/blog/e-book-news/how-to-add-custom-fonts-to-your-kobo-e-reader). Luckily, you've selected Kobo, which has an open environment, allowing installation of fonts.